# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with Pikaday datepicker in Livewire and Alpine.js integration

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, pikaday

I hope you're all doing well. I'm facing an issue while using the Pikaday datepicker plugin with Livewire v3 in my Laravel project.

To implement the datepicker, I followed the tutorial from https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/s4-date-picker, and I used Alpine.js as the JavaScript framework.

In my input-date.blade.php file, I have the following code:

```
<div x-data x-init="new Pikaday({ field: $refs.input })">
    <input
        class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
        x-ref="input"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    />
</div>
```

And in my app.js file, I have the following setup for Alpine.js and Pikaday:

```
import './bootstrap';
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import Pikaday from 'pikaday';

window.Alpine = Alpine;
window.Pikaday = Pikaday;

Alpine.start();
```

In my Livewire component, I use the datepicker as follows:

```
<div>
    <label for="active_since" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Aktiv seit</label>
    <x-input-date wire:model.lazy="active_since" id="active_since" />
</div>
```

The datepicker seems to be working fine, but every time I change the date, the following error occurs in the browser console:

```
app-44e1e891.js:11 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at J (app-44e1e891.js:11:1403)
    at wn.setDate (app-44e1e891.js:11:10067)
    at u._onInputChange (app-44e1e891.js:11:7060)
    at J (app-44e1e891.js:11:1403)
    at wn.setDate (app-44e1e891.js:11:10067)
    at u._onInputChange (app-44e1e891.js:11:7060)
    at J (app-44e1e891.js:11:1403)
    at wn.setDate (app-44e1e891.js:11:10067)
    at u._onInputChange (app-44e1e891.js:11:7060)
    at J (app-44e1e891.js:11:1403)
```

I've checked the implementation against the tutorial, and I'm using the latest versions of Livewire and Pikaday. However, I can't seem to figure out why this error is happening.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue when using Pikaday with Livewire and Alpine.js? Is there anything I might be missing or any suggestions on how to debug and resolve this error?

I would greatly appreciate any help or insights you can provide. Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Livewire 3 with Alpine and I believe it is a bug. For now I was able to work around it by replacing the refs with id reference. So in your own case, I will change

```
<div x-data x-init="new Pikaday({ field: $refs.input })">
    <input
        class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
        x-ref="input"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    />
</div>
```

to

```
<div x-data x-init="new Pikaday({ field: document.querySelector('#input') })">
    <input
        class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
        id="input"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes }}
    />
</div>
```

Once I made a similar change for my issue, it worked.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Still strugglig to make Pikaday work with Livewire 3. It worked with Livewire 2.

`<div x-data x-init="new Pikaday({field: document.querySelector('#start-date')})">
    <input name="start-date" type="text" id="start-date" wire:model.blur="startDate"/>
</div>`
When I select a date, the `startDate` property in my Livewire component is still `null`. `"snapshot":"{\"data\":{\"startDate\":null,`